# When I run node app.js command it gives me error ` ENOENT, no such file or directory on .mime.types

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following script:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var port = 3700;
var request = require('request');
var redis = require('redis');


// Set View Path; Set Engine; Integrate with Express
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.set('view engine', "jade");
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);

// Public dir
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './public'))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
}));

var routes = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/', routes);

io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

console.log("Listening on port " + port);

var wbApp = require('./components/init');

module.exports = app;
```

The file name is **app.js**. When i run **node app.js** command it gives me the following error:

```
fs.js:500
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/user/projects/wbchat/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/types/mime.types'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:352:15)
    at Mime.load (/home/user/projects/wbchat/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js:54:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/projects/wbchat/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js:90:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Could you please help me how can i solve this problem. Also when i am commenting **var express = require('express')**, the error is gone.

Comment: Try doing `npm cache clean`. Also, are you use NEXE?

Comment: Is your node directory in line with the program directory. It usually works for me to have my program one level above the node modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run `npm install` to install all the dependencies? If you did, I would remove the folder `./npm_modules` and run `npm install` because you might have something corrupted.

Hopefully this would help.